# Is the following complex function Conformal ? In which points?

Tags: complex-analysis

1. So is the complex function $f: C -> C$ defined by $f(z) = e^z$ conformal?
2. In which points?

Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I know a complex function is conformal if it has a nonzero derivative in a point (or in all points). So taking the derivative and filling in a point should not give a zero.

So 
1. taking the derivative $f '(z) = e^z$ so yes it is conformal.
2. In all points.

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. A complex function is also conformal (but orientation-reversing) wherever its derivative is nonzero if its conjugate is analytic.

Comment: When is a holomorphic function not conformal?

Comment: In general where its derivative vanishes. For example, at $z = 0$, $z \mapsto z^2$ doubles the size of angles at the origin.